# Decimal validation for greater than zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have tried the following Regex to validate decimals that should be greater than zero

`@"^-?(?!0(,0+)?$)\d+(,\d{1,3})?$";` and `@"^[0-9]+\d*\.\d{3}$"` but this is not working as I expected. I need to fire validation when the value is `0.000` in remaining cases it should not.

```
Valid : 1,123.000
        1.000
        0.001
Invalid : 0 or 0.000
```

Comment: This regex is hard as you may have repeating groups separated by comma.

Comment: Remember to allow for locales which use space as digit separator, and those that use period for separator and comma for decimal point.

Answer (score 5):

This is very hard to do with a regex, but very easy *and much clearer* with a conversion function:

```
decimal d;
if (decimal.TryParse(input, out d) && d > 0.0m) {
  // Valid
} else {
  // Invalid
}
```

Edit: regular expressions are a very powerful tool for string processing and should be part of every programmers toolbox. But that are not always the right tool: sometimes one needs to reach for something else.

Comment: +1 much clearer and culture-aware.  Would be even clearer by using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as an argument to TryParse.

Comment: @Joe *and* explicit [`NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ew0seb73) of course... but given the regex alternative even the defaults are an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this I tested for few sample and it is working

This worked for me

`string expression= @"^(\()?[0-9]+(?>,[0-9]{3})*(?>\.[0-9]{3})?(?<!^[0\.]+)$";`

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("0.000", expression))
{
  //Failed
}

if (Regex.IsMatch("0.001", expression))
{
  //passed
}

if (Regex.IsMatch("1.023", expression))
{
  //passed
}

if (Regex.IsMatch("11,111,111.111", expression))
{
  //passed
}
```